# How to apply styling on a selected element on my website?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on creating a wordpress website.
I would like to format the social network icons differently than how they come in the theme I bought.
There is a way to add custom css to the theme but I cannot identify the exact element I would like to apply the custom styling.
Here is the website I am working on:
http://uj.job-center.hu/kapcsolat/
I would like to change the background of the facebook icon to blue under the contact info sidebar.
I tried this but it does not work.

```
div#social_links-widget-3 fusion-social-networks boxed-icons fusion-social-networks-wrapper fusion-social-network-icon fusion-tooltip fusion-facebook fusion-icon-facebook {background-color:#4a6ea9;}
```

Can someone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

`.fusion-social-networks boxed-icons.fusion-social-networks-wrapper a.fusion-social-network-icon.fusion-tooltip.fusion-facebook.fusion-icon-facebook {
    background-color: #4a6ea9;
}`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give me the desired result. It colors the background of the facebook icon at the top. Although I would like to change the background color of the fb icon in the middle part of the page under Kapcsolat:

Comment: i've amended the original answer. This now takes into account the `div` that the icon is sat within, so it should not conflict with the icon in the navigation bar (which has the same class).